# TypeORM check if column has changed

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite, express, typeorm

So, I'm using TypeORM with the ActiveRecord pattern and have this entity

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column()
  public username: string;

  @Column()
  public password: string;

  @BeforeInsert()
  public async hashPassword() {
    this.password = await hashPassword(this.password);
  }

}
```

now what I want to accomplish is rehashing my password when any given User changes BUT only if the password field changed. I have seen some answers where I should store the tempPassword as a field in the User class but if for some reason the server goes down I would lose that data. I have also seen some people suggest the Subscriber thing typeorm has and im interested in that but not exactly sure how I would implement this with that.
for reference this is how I would do what I want to do with mongoose

```js
UserSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  if (this.isModified("password") || this.isNew) {
    // hash the password
  }
})
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use AfterLoad decorator to store old password as a private temporary variable and compare it with the new password.

```
private tempPassword: string;
  @AfterLoad()
  storeOriginalPassword() {
    this.tempPassword = this.password;
  }

  @BeforeInsert()
  public async hashPassword() {
    if (this.password && this.password !== this.tempPassword) {
      this.password = await hashPassword(this.password);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [TypeOrm](https://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers/beforeupdate) documentation, You can define a method with any name in the entity and mark it with @BeforeUpdate decorator and **TypeORM** will call it before an existing entity is updated using repository/manager save.

```js
@BeforeUpdate()
  async updatePassword(): Promise<void> {
    this.password = await hashPassword(this.password);;
  }
```

You can check inside whatever you want, but I don't think it'll be necessary because if the password field is not changed it will be the same, and **ORM** will not update this column anyway. It'll only be updated if it's changed.

Mongoose provides us with the **isModified()** & **isNew()** methods because it does not handles the checks for you, you need to explicitly check if the field is actually modified or new.

Comment: That is not what I'm seeing. If I patch the record changing another column (i.e. email), the password gets rehashed no matter what. The problem is that the previously-hashed value gets rehashed, thus rendering the record inaccessible because the user has no way of knowing the password. More info here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2624